Urdu Text not displaying correctly on MoviePy
I'm trying to display urdu text in my video using moviepy.
The word I'm trying to display is "پرندہ" (bird), but in the output video, the text is:

being displayed from left to right and;
the characters are separate and not joined.

My code:
ur_text="پرندہ"

clip = VideoFileClip(filename="bg_video.mp4", audio=False)

ur_txt_clip = TextClip(txt=ur_text, font="Jameel-Noori-Nastaleeq", fontsize=40, color="black") \
    .set_position((0.75, 0.7), relative=True) \
    .set_duration(clip.duration) \
    .crossfadein(7)
video = CompositeVideoClip([clip, ur_txt_clip])
video.write_videofile("output.mp4")

Image of Urdu text displayed in moviepy output
Specs:

OS: Linux
Distro: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
IDE: VS Code (UTF-8 encoding settings) with a python3.12.3 venv.
Have also tested it on Windows 11.

Things I've tried:

Tested on different urdu words, yet the issue persists.
The Jameel-Noori-Nastaleeq font does exist as I've verified its existence through seeing the available fonts using TextClip.list('font').
I have the Jameel Noori Nastaleeq font saved locally and have also added the following code in my  /etc/ImageMagick-6/type-ghostscript.xml file:

<type name="Jameel Noori Nastaleeq Regular" fullname="Jameel Noori Nastaleeq Regular" family="Jameel Noori Nastaleeq Regular" style="normal" weight="400" stretch="normal" format="truetype" metrics="/usr/bin/share/fonts/Jameel Noori Nastaleeq Regular.tff" glyphs="/usr/bin/share/fonts/Jameel Noori Nastaleeq Regular.tff" />


I've tried all the solutions posted in response to a similar stackoverflow question but when I use arabic_reshaper along with bidi.algorithm.get_display, the text simply doesn't appear in the output video. Displaying the text through matplotlib (as suggested in one of the responses) is causing Glyph errors (have tried multiple urdu fonts).

Noteworthy: ChatGPT directed me to render the urdu text using the PIL library and then use that image in my moviepy code as an ImageClip to display the urdu text. This solution works but its a hassle of handling all the PIL code and then using it in moviepy (is this really an issue?).



Try composing the text as UTF-8. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#unicode

@fmw42, 404 URL error. What do you mean by that?

@Essa I do not understand your question. What do I mean about what?  What was your command? Did you create a UTF-file with the text in it as recommended?
